# How to make a Label using only code?

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a label to a form with the click of a button. When I use the code here it only adds 1 label, but I want to add an unlimited amount. Every time I click the button it only adds 1 label even if I change the name.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e  As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lbl As New label
    lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size
    lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 180) 'set your location
    lbl.Text = (TextBox1.Text) 'set your name
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim lbl As New label
lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size (if required)
lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 180) 'set your location
lbl.Text = "label text goes here" 'set the text for your label
Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection
```

I'll leave you to programatically set the location. You could use something like a global variable to keep count of how many labels have been created...

Comment: you might want to set the .text property of the label though so that you can see it

Answer (score 1):

adds a new linklabel for each item in a listbox i add 24 to the updown integer
each time it creates a new linklabel so my linklabel ends up in a different location.

Dim rightleft as integer =1018
Dim updown as integer= 56

Dim LLCount as integer

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Do
     Dim lklabel As New LinkLabel
     lklabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(65, 13)
     lklabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(rightleft, updown)
     lklabel.Text = ListBox1.Items(LLCount)
     lklabel.Name = "lklabel" & LLCount
     Me.Controls.Add(lklabel)
     updown += 24
     LLCount += 1
     Loop Until lnklbl = ListBox1.Items.Count
  end sub
```