# How to make a Label using vb code by clicking button

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a `label` to the `form` with a click of the button.

When I use that code here, it only adds 1 `label` but I want to add unlimited amount every time I click the button; it even adds 1 `label` even if I change the name.

Thank you every one.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim lbl As New label
        lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size
        lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 180) 'set your location
        lbl.Text = (TextBox1.Text) 'set your name
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection

 End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Label using only code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315315/how-to-make-a-label-using-only-code)

Comment: it was a previus question no one replied corectly

Comment: You are creating a new label in every button click but you are drawing it over the previous label. The labels are overlaping each other!

Comment: You will have to change the point every time. You could have fields, say x and y of type Integer, that when the button is clicked, these fields are incremented by a certain value. Then: New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)

Comment: YOU have to decide where YOU want the new label to appear in YOUR code by setting the location (indicated by `set your location` according to what YOU want.  We cant know where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a rehash of the previous 2 perfectly good answers.  Here it tries to make clear that at least the location and text must be set based on logic provided by the user

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

      ' YOU decide where EACH new label goes and pass the X,Y for each 
      ' new label; YOU decide on the text and pass it.  you can make them
      ' variables, but YOU have to do some of the thinking....

      ' <...> == information YOU provide
      Private x As integer = <where you want the new label>
      Private y as integer = <where you want the new label>
      Private txt as String = <Text for this new label>

      ' EXAMPLEs
      ' a) set text from a textbox
           ' txt = txtLblText.Text
      ' b) Set X position from another code integer variable
           ' x = thisX
      ' c) Set Y position from textbox input
           ' y = Integer.Parse(txtLblYPos.Text)

      Dim lbl as Label = MakeNewLabel(x, y, txt As string)

      Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  

End Sub


Friend function MakeNewLabel(x as integer, y as Integer, txt As String) as label
    Dim lbl As New label

    ' add other label props here as needed

    lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)       'set your size
    lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)  'set your location
    lbl.Text = txt

    Return lbl
End Function
```

Comment: thankyou so much friend and for your time and thank you all for helping i apriciate thehat

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by @jlvaquero, you are overlapping your labels. The reason for this is that you're not changing the Point where these labels are being added to the Form.

One solution is to have field variables that can adjust the Point.

```
  Private x As Integer = 12
  Private y As Integer = 180

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lbl As New label
    lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size
    lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y) 'set your location
    lbl.Text = (TextBox1.Text) 'set your name
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection
    x += 10 'arbitrary value, you could adjust y, too
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for that code it fantastic but it only adds 1 label and when i change the name of it it does not do anything thank you

Comment: it just still ads 1 label and then i click all i want and change the name all i want but it does not ad any other labels

Answer (score 0):

hello and thank you everyone for your great help i would no got that far without you her si the code that  i used

Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Name = "Label" & counter
    lbl.Size = New Size(150, 20)
    lbl.Location = New Point(200, counter * 22)
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text 'text on label
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    counter += 1
End Sub
```

End Class